# wrong list items get deleted instead of chosen items with custom list adapter

Tags: android

I've created a custom ListView with checkboxes. I wanted to delete the selected items on "Delete" menu option selection.
   I am handling the onCheckedChanged event on CheckBox. Here I maintain an ArrayList to note down the selected elements position. Now when the user selects the "Delete" menu item I do remove the choosen items from ListAdapter's ArrayList.

Below is my code,

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("first");
    names.add("second");
    names.add("three");
    names.add("four");
    names.add("five");
    names.add("six");
    names.add("seven");
    names.add("eight");
    names.add("nine");

    listAdapter = new SelfAdapter(this,names);

    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);                       
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
    int menuId = menuItem.getItemId();
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems;
    switch(menuId){
    case R.id.delitem:
        Log.d(TAG,"del item selected");
        selectedItems = listAdapter.getSelected();
           **//pick the selected position items and delete them from the
           // listadapter arraylist**
        for(Integer element: selectedItems){
          Log.d(TAG,"Selected:"+element.toString());
          names.remove(element.intValue());
          listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }          
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the code for custom adapter,

```
class SelfAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<String> names;
private String TAG = "SelfAdapter"; 
ArrayList<Integer> checkedPos; **//contains the selected items position**
public SelfAdapter(Context context, ArrayList names) {
    super(context,R.layout.checkboxnlist, names);
    this.context = (Activity) context;
    this.names = names;
    checkedPos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    final int listPosition = position;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkboxnlist,parent,false);            
        holder.chkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkvw);
        holder.txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvw);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtView.setText(names.get(position));
    holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(TAG,"listPosition:"+listPosition);
          if(isChecked){
              checkedPos.add(new Integer(listPosition));
          }
          else{
              checkedPos.remove(listPosition);
          }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getSelected(){
    return checkedPos;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView txtView;
    CheckBox chkBox;
}
```

}

Now the problem is that if select 1st,2nd items (for example) then I see the wrong items get deleted and the listview populate after this is completely wrong. Later if I attempt to delete the items it's throwing "Index out of bounds exception". I guess the code is going wrong in getView method.

Can some one help me in finding out what am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide specifics of what goes wrong? Which items do get deleted when you select 1st and 2nd items? What does the listview have afterwards?

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Whatever the items I select the items get deleted are completely different (there is no pattern)... say if I choose 1st and 2nd item then it deletes 8th and 9th item..but this is just an example ... there is no certain pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove elements from `names`, you also need to remove elements from the `checkedPos` array. Otherwise, the two arrays will have different lengths. Then when you try again, `checkedPos` will be longer than `names` and you end up with the index out of bounds exception.

Also, when you are deleting from `names`, you can't use a normal iterator through . If you are supposed to delete names at indexes 1 and 2, then when you delete name 1, name 2 moves up to position 1. But your indexing isn't updated accordingly. The easiest solution is to iterate backwards through the position array, deleting from the end of `names` before deleting from the beginning.

P.S. It's a little weird to switch from ordinal numbers ("first", "second") to cardinal numbers ("three", "four", etc.) in the middle of the list.

Comment: Thanks. Not completely solved my problem but it's very big hint I got ... :-)

Comment: Probably it would do to just clear the `checkedPos` array after deleting elements from `names`.

Comment: Thanks once again. Now just I did descending sort on the arraylist with position first(as the selected items are random), then I deleted each element from the "Data arrayList" and then cleared.  Fixed my complete problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

you must delete 
names = new ArrayList<  STRING  >();

but you delete  selectedItems;